# When is AllowVoidAsyncOperations set, when invoking async ActionResults?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous

**UPDATE**

After some thinking, I came to the conclusion, that I might not have asked the *right* question.

Given the following code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public Task<string> DownloadAsync(string url)
    {
        using (var web = new WebClient())
        {
            return web.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
        }
    }

    // THROWS EXCEPTION
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = DownloadAsync("http://google.dk");
        return Content(data.Result);
    }

    // WORKS
    public async Task<ActionResult> IndexWorks()
    {
        var data = await DownloadAsync("http://google.dk");
        return Content(data);
    }
}
```

It's obvious enough (especially after reading @Stephen Cleary's blog post), that the `ActionResult Index()` code will result in a deadlock. But why?

After some digging, I figured out that `.NET 4.5` introduces a new `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, that's supposed to be more "Task Friendly". Downloading the source code for `.NET 4.5` and taking a look inside the new `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, I figured that calling `OperationStarted`, will result in a check on a boolean named `AllowVoidAsyncOperations`. If the value is true, no problem. If the value however for this boolean is false it will throw the following exception:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous
>   operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or
>   module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this
>   exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is
>   marked <%@ Page Async=\"true\" %>.

Through a lot of reflection, I figured that, calling the `async Task<ActionResult> IndexWorks()` somehow sets the `AllowVoidAsyncOperations` to true. - While calling the synchronous version, it stays at it's default value: false.

**My question is therefore:**

When do the async ActionResult call the internal method of `AspNetSynchrnoizationContext`, that sets `AllowVoidAsyncOperations` to true? - I've so far narrowed it down to the class `CallHandlerExecutionStep` inside the `HttpApplication` class. - However, I'm not sure about how it decides whether to allow it or not.

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Please post the signature of the `Engine.GetBestMatch` method!

Answer (score 4):

This particular exception is thrown by ASP.NET if you try to perform an asynchronous operation at a point not permitted in the request lifecycle (or entirely outside of a request context).

You shouldn't be seeing this in ASP.NET MVC. There are two things to check:

1. Ensure you are running on .NET 4.5. I suspect you already are, or else you wouldn't see that message at all.
2. Ensure you have [`UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` set to `true` *or* have `httpRuntime.targetFramework` set to `4.5`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx).

**Update:** Upon reflection, there are another two conditions that could cause this in ASP.NET MVC:

1. Ensure you are not calling any `async void` methods.
2. Ensure you are not using EAP components. For example:

   1. `HttpClient` is [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx), so it would work.
   2. `HttpWebRequest` is [APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx), so a TAP wrapper around it would work.
   3. `WebClient` is [EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx), so it would cause this error. This is true whether you use `DownloadStringAsync` or `DownloadStringTaskAsync`.

Comment: I've verified that I'm indeed using .NET 4.5, and that `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` is set to `true`.

Comment: I suspect that the real cause, is as described in one of your blog posts, a deadlock (blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). - ASP.NET somehow is able to detect that, and therefore throws an exception. - Although I might very well be wrong.

Comment: I would expect a deadlock on .NET 4.5 with `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext`, but I would not expect this exception. To my knowledge, there is no framework code (today) that detects that kind of deadlock.

Comment: See updated answer. I suspect your code is using `WebClient`; if you change it to `HttpClient`, you should see a proper deadlock.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `WebClient DownloadStringTaskAsync` - however, as already mentioned in my post, then using the new async/await works fine. - So what is causing the first code example to fail on this piece of code? What is different from code example 2? (SynchronizationContext, ExecutionContext....).

Comment: Also using `HttpClient` simply turns the exception into a `TaskCanceledException` instead.

Comment: With code example 1, MVC knows your action is not asynchronous, so it activates a state where it will not allow any `async void` methods. This also affects EAP objects.

Comment: Regarding `TaskCanceledException`, you'll have to examine your own code for the cause of that.

Comment: Call me crazy, call me insane.. but take a look at my update - and thanks for hanging on! :)

Comment: I think those would be better as separate questions.

Comment: You're right. The questions about the callstack would fit better elsewhere. I've updated the post once again, this time with the question I _actually_ was looking for an answer on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find the code which sets up UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext to true, because the code which sets it up is not part of .NET framework.

Code which manipulates synchronization context is produced by c# 5.0 compiler during compilation. C# compiler creates a state machine struct with weird name like `<yourmethod>d__0`( to avoid conflict with your code). There is a methond within this struct called "MoveNext". That is the place where sync context is captured. And most of your async code will be moved there as well by compiler.